# PHP get next ID from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database with auto incrementing ID's, each entry has a youtube videoID which is a varchar. So when the page loads it echos the first entry (ID 1), when you click the button it prints the next entry (ID 2). How would i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Auto-increment can only be used on an integer field. It would be a lot of help if you could provide the definition of the table in question, as well as your expected output and what queries you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So when the page loads it echos the first entry (ID 1), when you click the button it prints the next entry (ID 2). How would i do this?

This sounds like ordering and paging.  (Even with a "page" size of only 1.)  Basically select all records greater than the "current" ID, ordered by ID, limited to 1.  Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE ID > ?
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT 1
```

So if your records are:

```
ID | Value
----------
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
4  | D
5  | E
```

and you supply `3` as the "current ID" (the one currently being viewed on the page where the "next" link is rendered), then the query would return

```
4  | D
```

Because `4` and `5` satisfy the `WHERE` condition, you sort by `ID` so `4` is first, and you limit the results to `1` record.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code to get the id that was inserted into the last auto incremented column value is `mysql_insert_id()` or `mysql_insert_id($connection)`.  However, I'm not sure why you are writing about a *string*, auto incremented columns are **always** *integers*.

Comment: There's also the `SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name` approach.

Comment: I have updated the question. Thanks

Comment: @tadman: That would give you the *last* `id` (at least in all cases I know of), but not the *next* `id`.

Comment: @David The "next" ID is highly configuration dependent, but the default is at least +1. It could be +2 or +10 or something else if that's the increment set on the server config. If this is "next in sequence of already saved records" then `SELECT MIN(id) FROM table_name WHERE id>?` given an existing `id` value.

Comment: @tadman: In the majority of cases, yes.  But it's in no way guaranteed.  A record could have been inserted and deleted, a transaction rolled back, a record could be inserted in the milliseconds since fetching and manually incrementing the ID, a set of IDs reserved by a database engine optimization, etc.  While it's common for the next ID to be 1 greater than the last, it's also a common bug to *assume* this to be the case.

Comment: @David Given that the next ID is fundamentally a mystery until such a time as someone creates the record I tried to avoid touching on that issue.

Comment: @tadman: On that we completely agree.  I think it's moot anyway, the question has changed since this answer was posted and it sounds to me like the OP is asking to find the "next" of an existing set of records, not predict the ID for a new record.